# RabbitMQ throwing TimeOut exception on .CreateModel()

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, timeout

I've created a Bus application to encapsulate all the subscribe and publish to a RabbitMQ broker. This bus is then used as a SDK for others projects of mine. After running this projects (whitch is basicaclly for applications comunicating via RabbitMQ messages using my Bus sdk), I realized that the Bus was throwing a exception a TimeOut exception on the native method .CreateModel(), as follows:

```
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at RabbitMQ.Util.BlockingCell.GetValue(TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelRpc(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, Byte[] body)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Model._Private_ChannelOpen(String outOfBand)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.CreateNonRecoveringModel()
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.CreateModel()
```

Here are some information about the my RabbitMQ broker:
   Version: 3.7.2
   Erlang:  20.1
   OS: Linux Ubuntu (AWS)

Here is my RabbitMQConnection class:

```
internal class RabbitMQConnection : IDisposable
{
    private object __syncRoot__ { get; } = new object();

    #region Private
    private bool __disposed__ { get; set; }
    private IConnectionFactory __rmqConnFactory__ { get; }
    private IConnection __rmqConnection__ { get; set; }
    private string __connectionIdentifier__ { get; }
    private ILog __logger__ { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Public
    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get
        {
            DisposeCheck();
            return __rmqConnection__ != null && __rmqConnection__.IsOpen && !__disposed__;
        }
    }

    public int ThreadLimit { get; private set; }

    public IConnection GetConnection
    {
        get
        {
            DisposeCheck();
            if (IsConnected == true)
            {
                return __rmqConnection__;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDisposed
    {
        get
        {
            return __disposed__;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public RabbitMQConnection(RabbitMQConfiguration _rmqConfig)
    {
        __logger__ = LogProvider.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        ConnectionFactory rMQconnFactory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = _rmqConfig.Hostname,
            UserName = _rmqConfig.Username,
            Password = _rmqConfig.Password,
            VirtualHost = _rmqConfig.VirtualHost,
            AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
            DispatchConsumersAsync = true,
        };

        __rmqConnFactory__ = rMQconnFactory;

        ThreadLimit = _rmqConfig.ThreadLimit;

        __connectionIdentifier__ = $"{_rmqConfig.CurrentMachineIPAddress} - {_rmqConfig.CurrentMachineHostname}";

        Connect();

        __disposed__ = false;
    }

    private void Connect()
    {
        DisposeCheck();

        if (__rmqConnection__ == null)
        {
            lock (__syncRoot__)
            {
                if (__rmqConnection__ == null)
                {
                    __rmqConnection__ = __rmqConnFactory__.CreateConnection(__connectionIdentifier__);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IModel CreateChannel()
    {

        DisposeCheck();

        if (!IsConnected)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No RabbitMQ connections are available to perform this action");
        }

        return __rmqConnection__.CreateModel(); // Here is where the exception occurs!!!
    }

    #region ShutdownEvents
    private void OnConnectionBlocked(object sender, ConnectionBlockedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (__disposed__) return;

        //Logar algo
        __logger__.Warn("A RabbitMQ connection (OnConnectionBlocked) is shutdown. Trying to re-connect...");
    }

    void OnCallbackException(object sender, CallbackExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (__disposed__) return;

        //Logar algo
        __logger__.Warn(e?.Exception, "A RabbitMQ connection (OnCallbackException) is shutdown. Trying to re-connect...");
    }

    void OnConnectionShutdown(object sender, ShutdownEventArgs reason)
    {
        if (__disposed__) return;

        //Logar algo
        __logger__.Warn("A RabbitMQ connection (OnConnectionShutdown) is on shutdown. Trying to re-connect...");
    }
    #endregion

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (__disposed__ == true)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            __rmqConnection__?.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log here
            __logger__.Fatal(ex, "RabbitMQ Connection: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            __disposed__ = true;
        }
    }

    private void DisposeCheck()
    {
        if (__disposed__ == true)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("RabbitMQConnection");
        }
    }
}
```

The exception occurs in the line:

```
return __rmqConnection__.CreateModel();
```

Does anyone has any ideia of why that happens? I know that sometimes the RabbitMQ connection may oscillate, but I've heard that the RabbitMQ has a native retry to when that happens.

Comment: It's helpful to let people know the version of the software you're using (RabbitMQ, Erlang and operating system), and if anything is in the RabbitMQ log. You should also do a TCP capture on port 5672 to see if a connection is even successful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much relevant its now. 
Exception is {System.TimeoutException} The operation has timed out. 
If we remove **AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true** in connection factory, not generating exception and channel is created.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth; I've had this error when there were *too many channels* already created on the `IConnection`. The error didn't indicate this unfortunately, but scaling down the number of channels stopped the error from happening.

The max number of channels can be set both in the [client and server](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html#channel-max).